# Rails + Ransack gem: Sorting by associations attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a `Book` model that has many `BookVersion`s. `BookVersion` has two columns: `name, isbn`.

I want to be able to sort @book.book_versions ISBNs only for the @book.book_versions that has a `name == 'lb'`

What would I put here in the view? The issue is that I will have 3 of them.

I'm looking for something like this:

`<%= sort_link @search, :book_versions_with_name_eq_lb_sort_by_isbn %>`

`<%= sort_link @search, :book_versions_with_name_eq_pb_sort_by_isbn %>`

`<%= sort_link @search, :book_versions_with_name_eq_hc_sort_by_isbn %>`

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could show what the view should look like.

Anywho, from what you've described I would separate the search and sort similar to this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack). The "value" field you could use a fixed drop-down select with "lb", "pb" & "hc" instead of the text field used in the sample.

HTH